# How to fix Angular refresh problem?(I want to use useHash for some reason)

Tags: angular

I use angular for one multi page application and I use UseHash for some reason but when I want to share some page from my application the server side remove my url after #. I want to use old route strategy for some reason. how can I fix it?

Comment: "I use UseHash", "I want to use useHash", "I want to use old route strategy" and the rest of the info you provide (very little) do not really sit comfortably next to each other. Please rephrase. If possible provide more info. Explain what blocks you. Consider providing a [mre]. Taking the [tour] and reading [ask] is highly recommended.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.